# How to convert multiple mha images to nii

Tags: python

I would like to convert about 300 .mha images into .nii format. Which are under subfolders . I have successfully converted one image but in order to go each folder and convert, its a tidious task. Please suggest me code that is functioning with sitk library

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

OUTPUT_DIR = '/home/user/Downloads/'

Image = sitk.ReadImage('Input dir')
print(Image.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
sitk.WriteImage(Image, os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'Flair.nii'))
```

Comment: Could you explain files hierarchy

Comment: Its ubuntu os. /home/user/Downloads/brats2015_training/BRATS2015_Training/HGG/brats_2013_pat0001_1/VSD.Brain.XX.O.MR_Flair.54512

Comment: This is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

Use python's **os.walk** method to get all the files in a directory tree.  Then select out only the ones with the '.mha' suffix.

Here's an example of how it works:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Or you can try and decipher the **os** library documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html